# Что означает .LC0: .long в ассемблере?

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc

Изучаю ассемблерный код одной программы на Си
вот её оригинал

```
i3 = 1 + 2;
flt_1 = 2.4 + 6.3;
i2 = 5;
```

А в ассемблере это выглядит таким образом:

```
movl    $3, i3(%rip)
movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
movsd   %xmm0, flt_1(%rip)
movl    $5, i2(%rip)
```

Понимаю,что это AT&T синтаксис и вижу регистры для чисел с плавающей точкой.

Но не понимаю, почему у переменной стоит в скобках регистр.Просто это похоже на аналогию смещения *-16(%rbp)*.Так ли это?

Не понимаю, почему вдруг появилась метка с всё теми же скобками, если перейти по ней , видно следующее:

```
.LC0:
    .long   1717986918
    .long   1075930726
    .align 8
```

Что это означает ?
И ещё один вопрос:EDX:EAX что это означает?

Comment: Сумма 2.4+6.3 вычислена во время компиляции и сохранена (думаю, что в .rodata) по метке .LC0 в виде IEEE754 64-bit double. Вторая и третья команда пересылают её из константы в переменную (потому что прямого MOVSD память-память не бывает). В интеловом синтаксисе это "movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]"

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy если тянет на ответ (в чём я не до конца уверен) — с нашим удовольствием.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сумма 2.4+6.3 вычислена во время компиляции и сохранена (думаю, что в .rodata) по метке .LC0 в виде IEEE754 64-bit double. Вторая и третья команда пересылают её из константы в переменную (потому что прямого MOVSD память-память не бывает). В интеловом синтаксисе это `movsd xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]` и `movsd QWORD PTR flt_1[rip], xmm0` соответственно.